# MSBuild task to make use of Teamcity credentails

Tags: msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0, teamcity-7.1

I am using MSBuild task to install a windows service. Everything works fine but the newly installed service runs under local system account. Is there anyway to tell MSBuild to install the service under the same account as TeamCity (TeamCity is running under a special service account). I am runing the build file using TeamCity. I dont want to explicitly specify the user name and password as it is too risky to store this information in plain text.

[image: Build Param does not allow values to be stored as password]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem possible. However, I'd suggest to use Build Parameters instead, they're designed for it. 
Read more about it here: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD6/Defining+and+Using+Build+Parameters+in+Build+Configuration

You'll be able to specify user/password in TeamCity UI (even on every build, if needed)

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. when I use build params (adding them as Config, Environment, System params) they are stored as plain text within the team city (correct me if I am wrong). And thats again little risky. Is there any way to store these value after encryption.

Comment: When you choose control type - "Password", then, I believe, it is stored as an encrypted string.

Comment: Thank once again for reply. I have attached an image to the original question. It shows how how I am adding these parameters. I dont see an option to add anything parameter as password. I am usin gTeam City version 7.1

Comment: Just click on Specs -> Edit

Comment: Thank you reply. Yes i was able to mask the value by changing the spec to password. I am marking your solution as answer.